# How to add read more option in PHP

Tags: php, substr

I have a paragraph with more than five lines. But i don't want to show all the paragraph. I would like to add 'read more' option at the end of second line. If user clicks the option after it goes to other page in PHP or using javascript.

Ex:
        Each participant needs to bring his or her best dish. The judges will initially assign a score to each of the dishes. Now, several rounds will follow. In each round, any two chefs will be called up on the stage. Each of the chefs can then choose any one dish to battle against the other chef and the one having the dish with the higher score will win this round

But i need the following output

Each participant needs to bring his or her best dish. The judges will initially assign a score to each of the... [read more].

Please suggest any idea!

Thank you.

Comment: You need to show the code you've attempted already.

Comment: Do some google search, you'll find obviously a lot...

Comment: Read here: http://bg2.php.net/substr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilise `substr()` where `$string` is equal to your string of text:

```
<?php

$string = 'String of text that you want to shorten';

// Starts at the beginning of the string and ends after 100 characters 
echo substr($string, 0, 100).'... <a href="page.php">Read More</a>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
$words = preg_split('/\s+/', $string, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

to get the words and do an `array_range()` call with the `$words` array. And generate a summary string with `implode(null, $selectedArrayRange) . ' <a href="#">read more</a>'`.

Answer (score -1):

It is so simple with jquery.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Example</title>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<?php

echo ('<p> this is a paragraph </p><button class="one">read more</button>');
echo ('<p class="two"> this is more</p>');

?>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(e) {
                $(".two").hide();
                $(".one").mouseenter(function(e) {
                            $(".two").show("blind");
                        });
                $(".one").mouseleave(function(e) {
                            $(".two").hide("blind");
                        });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

see the result here:
[example](http://cclever.ir/test/example.php)

Comment: It can be done with just php. There is no real need for a jQuery solution as OP has said it is to link through to another page